How to force the event emmiter of NestJs to not use Promise.all and instead use for await
How to force the event emmiter of NestJs to not use Promise.all and instead use for await?
i have a modular event driven monolith application written with NestJs i have module A, B and C A will emit an event, both module B and C will listen they will both share the same global transaction for data consistency, i need one of two ways (as much as i have discovered), either force each module to be fully done (ie await it) with the event handling, or use locking between modules(which is complicated because each module will start a child transaction, and i dont seem to find a way to keep each module in a nested transaction only concerned with its child transaction -- and isolated from other child transactions .... so this is not the solution that i will go with )
it is much easier to simply force the event handler to use for await to handle each event fully before going to the next event instead of using promise.All
so how can i do that?
i tried using all modes if event emission, emit, emitAsync, with or without await.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case instead of describing code
